# Execution sequence inside a jquery event handler

Tags: jquery

I have a big issue with the execution squence inside this jquery handler :
Was wondering if anyone has come accross this before:

I have a simple form:

```
<form action='foo.cgi' id='myForm' >
<input type=text name='name' />
<input type=submit value='Find it!'/>
</form>
```

when user clicks on Find it! would like to change the cursor to 'progress' before the data is returned through an ajax call:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#myForm ").submit(function(){

   $("body").css("cursor", "progress") ;

   htmlobj=$.ajax({url:server_url,..........);

   }

 }
```

However: The cursor [line 2 above ] does not change until data is returned through ajax - Seems like line 3. gets executed before 2.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The rest of your submit function would aid in debugging.

Comment: try changing ur input type to "button"...

Comment: Sometimes it requires a mouse move in order for the cursor to update. Are you certain that it isn't merely because you haven't moved the mouse yet?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      //This will be called when your ajax start
     $("body").ajaxStart( function(){
           $(this).css("cursor", "progress") ;
     });

     //this will be called once ajax stop
     $("body").ajaxStop(function(){
         $(this).css("cursor", "pointer") ;
     });

    $("#myForm ").submit(function(){

           htmlobj=$.ajax({url:server_url,..........);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just that the page does not have a chance to update because it is busy working on the ajax call.

You could move the ajax call into a timeout function, so that the cursor update has a chance to execute. Something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#myForm ").submit(function(){

   $("body").css("cursor", "progress") ;
   setTimeout(performAjax,100);

   }

 }

function performAjax() {
    htmlobj=$.ajax({url:server_url,..........);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but that was the first thing i tried - same result - I have also tried inserting a beforeSend arg in $.ajax where i turn the cursor to progress - same thing - when i comment ou the ajax call the behavior is as expected: curso turns to progress